# SPARQL query to get all patients who have both Asthma and Diabetes

Tags: sparql

I have three classes, Patient ID, Asthma and Diabetes. So I need to get all patient id's who have both Asthma and Diabetes.

I tried the below mentioned query,

```
 PREFIX ioi:<http://io-informatics.com/rdf/>
 PREFIX ns:<http://io-informatics.com/rdf/Asthma#>
 PREFIX ns2:<http://io-informatics.com/rdf/Diabetes#>


         SELECT DISTINCT * 
                WHERE {
                ?s a ioi:PseudoPatientID
                {   ?s ?p  ns2:DIAB   }
                  UNION
                {    ?s ?p ns:ASTHMA   }

           }
```

But this query gives me patients who have diabetes and patients who have asthma. It does not give me common patients who have both Asthma and Diabetes.

I kind of want boolean AND condition here where i get those who have Diabetes and Asthma.

How do i get this result through SPARQL query?

Comment: Why is `?p` a variable here?  It seems like it would make more sense if it were a definite property (e.g., `hasCondition`).  Can you show a sample of your data?  We can make attempts to "fix" this query, but without seeing at least a sample of your data, there's no guarantee that the fix will be correct.  Furthermore, if Asthma and Diabetes are _classes_ (not individuals), it seems more likely that a patient would be related to an instance of them rather than the class itself.

Comment: The basic triple patterns _is_ an "AND" matching.  If you want something that has both conditions, you'd do something like `?x :hasCondition :Asthma . ?x :hasConditions :Diabetes .`, or (even shorter, but equivalent) `?x :hasCondition :Asthma, :Diabetes.`  However, you said that Asthma and Diabetes are _classes_ so the patient might actually be related to instances of those, in which you'd use `?x :hasCondition/rdf:type :Asthma, :Diabetes .`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put both conditions in the where clause, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
    WHERE {
       ?s a ioi:PseudoPatientID.
       ?s ?p ns2:DIAB.
       ?s ?p ns:ASTHMA.
    }
```

assuming the the predicate `?p` is the same in both cases.
if the predicate is not the same you can either:

- substitute the second `?p` with something else, or
- specify the predicate.

Comment: Without seeing the data, it's hard to know whether this is correct or not.  @sraf said that "I have three classes, Patient ID, Asthma and Diabetes";  if Diabetes and Asthma are classes, it seems more likely that either the id is related to _instances_ of those classes, or that the id is an instance of those classes (this seems strange, but it could be how the model is set up).  It seems less likely that the id would be directly related to the _classes_ Asthma and Diabetes themselves.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, while I see your points, this proposal seems the logical consequence of the OP getting the *union* of patients with either diabetes or asthma with the original query.

Comment: Agreed;  if the OP's query is returning some of what OP wants, then this would seem to be the correct modification.  You could even shorten this a bit: `?s a ioi:PseudoPatientID ; ?p ns2:DIAB, ns2:ASTMHA` or `?s a ioi:PseudoPatientID ; ?p1 ns2:DIAB ; ?p2 ns2:ASTMHA`, depending on whether `?p` is supposed to be the same in each case.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: For the queries mentioned by you, i get no results. In the sample data that we have, the instances of PseudopatientID class are related to instances of Asthma and Diabates class, the instances of each of these classes being, ASTHMA and DIAB.

Comment: @kr1: Thanks for the query, i get the required results from the query submitted by you.